# php parse_ini_file oop & deep

Tags: php, parsing, config, ini

I would like to make use of somehting like [parse_ini_file][1].

Lets say for instance I have a boot.ini file that I will load for further procedure:

```
    ;database connection settings
[database]
type        =   mysql;
host        =   localhost;
username    =   root;
password    =   "";
dbName      =   wit;
```

However, I would like to have it in a different way as the php array would be:

```
$ini['database']['whatever']
```

So first of all I would like to have my boot.ini like this structure:

```
;database settings (comment same style)
db.host1.type = mysql;
db.host1.host = localhost;
db.host1.username = root;
db.host1.password = "";
db.host1.dbName = wit;

db.host2.type = mysql;
db.host2.host = otherHost;
db.host2.username = root;
db.host2.password = "";
db.host2.dbName = wit;
```

So when I now access the file I would like to access it this way:

```
$ini['db']['host1']['whatever']
```

And on top of that I would like to do it via OOP so lets say:
$ini->db->host1->whatever

```
or `$ini->db->host1`
```

will return an array with all the attributes such as type, host, username, password and the dbName;

I appreciate anykind of help. Thank you very much in advance.

```
  [1]: http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you need to postprocess the [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/parse_ini_file) result array then.

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("bootstrap.ini");

$ini = new stdclass;
foreach ($ini_array as $key=>$value) {
    $c = $ini;
    foreach (explode(".", $key) as $key) {
        if (!isset($c->$key)) {
            $c->$key = new stdclass;
        }
        $prev = $c;
        $c = $c->$key;
    }
    $prev->$key = $value;
}
```

**Update** Hackety-Hack. Now using an extra `$prev` to unset the last object level again. (A for loop to detect the last $key would have worked better).

If you want to use the array syntax *and* the object syntax, then replace the `new stdclass` with `new ArrayObject(array(), 2);`.

Comment: Uhm, I think your is nicer, since it has fewer lines and fewer conditions. I also wanted to move `$prev->$key = $value;` out of loop, but in some reason decided that `$last` hack will be better. Well it is not, `$prev` is more handy in this case ;-)

Comment: Well the $prev hack pollutes the local scope with an extra variable, and creates an temporary object, then overwrites it, so it probably fragments the heap a bit more. Hencewhy the $last check is likely also quicker. -- Anyway, turned out to have more edge cases than expected.. :]

Comment: heap fragmentation is the last thing I ever think of when program using php )))

Comment: perfect, thank you very much! actually it seems very simple, as you are just working exploding the string and depending on that you continue - hmm why did I not think about that :((

Answer (score 3):

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sample.ini");

$ini = new stdclass;
foreach ($ini_array as $key => $value) {
    $last = substr(strrchr($key, '.'), 1);
    if (!$last) $last = $key;

    $node = $ini;

    foreach (explode('.', $key) as $key2) {
        if (!isset($node->$key2)) {
            $node->$key2 = new stdclass;
        }

        if ($key2 == $last) {
            $node->$key2 = $value;
        } else {
            $node = $node->$key2;
        }
    }

}

var_dump($ini->db->host1->type);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an elegant solution for you. This implementation allows inheritance and vectors using dots as our collegue "zerkms" showed us before. In truth, I took his solution and improved it. Thus the solution be like Zend Parser :) I tested it and works. But, as we know, is impossible test all possibilities. Then, I hope attent people detect troubles and propose corrections.

Here goes the code (as a function):

```
function parse($filename) {

        $ini_array = parse_ini_file ( $filename, true );

        if (! $ini_array)
            throw new Exception ( 'Error on parsing ini file!', - 1 );

        $ini = new stdClass ();

        //Parse section...
        foreach ( $ini_array as $namespace => $prop ) {

            $section = $namespace;
            $ext = explode ( ':', $namespace );

            if (count ( $ext ) == 2) {

                $section = trim ( $ext [0] );
                $extend = trim ( $ext [1] );

                if (! isset ( $ini->$extend ))
                    throw new Exception ( 'Parent section doesn\'t exists!', - 1 );

                $ini->$section = clone $ini->$extend;

            } else
                $ini->$section = new stdClass ();

            foreach ( $prop as $key => $value ) {

                $arr = explode ( '.', $key );
                $n = count ( $arr ) - 1;

                if ($n) {
                    $aux = $ini->$section;
                    for($i = 0; $i < $n; ++ $i) {

                        if(!isset($aux->$arr [$i]))
                            $aux->$arr [$i] = new stdClass ();

                        $aux = $aux->$arr [$i];
                    }
                    $aux->$arr [$n] = $value;
                } else
                    $ini->$section->$key = $value;

            }

        }

        return $ini;

}
```

And here goes an example of .ini file:

[environment]
env_name = production
x.y = 3

[oi : environment]
z = 5