# PHP: Dynamic multidimensional array with N number of elements

Tags: php, dynamic, random, multidimensional-array, element

I'm trying to create an array that contains a config file, but I'm having trouble when some of the keys has the same name. Let's say I have a config in this kind of format:

```
dinner=salad
dish.fruit.first.name=apple
dish.fruit.first.juicy=true
dish.fruit.second.name=lettuce
dish.fruit.second.juicy=false
dressing.name=french
dressing.tasty=true
```

and that would be turned into an array like this with the idea, that there can be any amount of comma seperated key values:

```
Array
(
  [dinner] => "salad"
  [dish] => Array
  (
    [fruit] => Array
    (
      [first] => Array
      (
        [name] => "apple"
        [juicy] => "true"
      )
      [second] => Array
      (
        [name] => "lettuce"
        [juicy] => "false"
      )
    )
  )
  [dressing] => Array
  (
    [name] => "french"
    [tasty] => "true"
  )
)
```

But I'm unable to get my head around it. I've tried creating a foreach loop and inserting new array into the last array via references, but it takes only the first key set starting with same name. Here's my current code and the result:

```
    $config = array();
    $filehandle = @fopen($filename, "r");
    while (!feof($filehandle))
    {
        $line           = ereg_replace("/\n\r|\r\n|\n|\r/", "", fgets($filehandle, 4096));
        $configArray    = explode("=", $line);
        $configKeys     = explode(".", $configArray[0]);
        $configValue    = $configArray[1];

        foreach ($configKeys as $key)
        {
            if (isset($head))
            {
                $last[$key] = array();
                $last = &$last[$key];
            }
            else
            {
                $head[$key] = array();
                $last = &$head[$key];
            }
        }
        $last = $configValue;
        $config += $head;
        unset($head);
        unset($last);
    }
    fclose($filehandle);
```

result:

```
Array
(
  [dinnes] => "salad"
  [dish] => Array
  (
    [fruit] => Array
    (
      [first] => Array
      (
        [name] => "apple"
      )
    )
  )
  [dressing] => Array
  (
    [name] => "french"
  )
)
```

Comment: Have you considered instead a different format for the configuration file? A JSON object would be trivial to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were various problems in it.

The `$config += $head;` assignment would have overwritten entries. Prefer [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge) for such cases. And also `$head` was undefined; no idea where it came from.

Another simplification is just traversing the array structure using `= &$last[$key]`. This implicitly defines the subarray. But you could of course retain the [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) or use [`settype`](http://php.net/settype) for explicity.

```
$config = array();
$filehandle = @fopen(2, "r");
while (!feof($filehandle))
{
    $line           = ereg_replace("/\n\r|\r\n|\n|\r/", "", fgets($filehandle, 4096));
    $configArray    = explode("=", $line);
    $configKeys     = explode(".", $configArray[0]);
    $configValue    = $configArray[1];

    $last = &$config;
    foreach ($configKeys as $key)
    {
            $last = &$last[$key];
    }
    $last = $configValue;

}
fclose($filehandle);
```

Btw, the [`ereg`](http://php.net/ereg) functions are somewhat outdated. And you could simplify this much more using a single [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) or better yet reading in the ini-style file using [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/parse_ini_file).  - (See similar answer here [php parse_ini_file oop & deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724265/php-parse-ini-file-oop-deep/5724350#5724350), albeit that uses an object structure.)

Comment: hot diggity, thanks! yes, that makes sense now that I see it. I knew there were easier solution to this :P